# proto import file not found (project was managed by bazel), How can I set the import path correctly?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-rules, protobuf-c

I use bazel to manage my project and I want to generate protobuf files by bazel build. Here is my file path tree:
[image]

There are two problems:

1. How to make geometry.proto import matrix.proto (in the same folder)?

   syntax = "proto2";
   import "matrix.proto";
   package sample.proto;

but there is an error:
[image]

2. How can I let external_proto/xxx.proto import lam_common/xxx.proto?

This Is the BUILD file:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_proto_library")
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")

proto_library(
    name = "lam_common",
    srcs = [
        "lam_common/geometry.proto",
        "lam_common/matrix.proto",
        "lam_common/projection.proto",
    ],
    import_prefix = "proto",
)

proto_library(
    name = "external_proto",
    srcs = [
        "external_proto/config_camera.proto",
        "external_proto/config_filter.proto",
        "external_proto/config_multi_sensors_fusion.proto",
        "external_proto/config_navigation_device.proto",
        "external_proto/config_region.proto",
        "external_proto/config_static_detector.proto",
        "external_proto/debug_internal_ekf_state.proto",
        "external_proto/debug_states.proto",
        "external_proto/keyframe_states.proto",
        "external_proto/layer_pose.proto",
        "external_proto/lidar_icp_poses.proto",
        "external_proto/loop_detection_poses.proto",
        "external_proto/novatel_raw_data.proto",
        "external_proto/perception_object.proto",
        "external_proto/prediction.proto",
        "external_proto/static_detection_segments.proto",
        "external_proto/stream.proto",
        "external_proto/tile_points_storage.proto",
    ],
    deps =
        [":lam_common"],
)

cc_proto_library(
    name = "external_proto_cc",
    deps = [":external_proto"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use import "proto/lam_common/xxx.proto", then the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chaning all of the import statements in the proto files, you can pass in the `strip_import_prefix = "lam_common"` to `proto_library`.